# Store specific elements to manipulate later

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to toggle a specific selection of elements. I want to hide elements based on a selection, then show those exact same elements. I tried to use this code but the rows don't "show" because it seems to re-check which ones are visible.

```
jQuery(function($){
        $('input[id^=_cmb_api_use_defaults_]').click(function(){
                var $rows = $(this).parents('tr:first').nextAll('tr:visible');
                if($(this).is(':checked')){
                        $rows.hide();
                } else {
                        $rows.show();
                }
        });
});
```

How can I store those specific elements, so i can manipulate the exact same table rows later?

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo to make your problem easier to understand. What do you mean by *"it seems to re-check which ones are visible"*?

Comment: I can't tell without seeing some HTML, but I suspect that `.parents()` isn't doing what you expect. [Consider using `.closest()` instead](http://api.jquery.com/closest).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use a variable declared outside the function:

```
jQuery(function($){
        $('input[id^=_cmb_api_use_defaults_]').each(function(i, input) {
            var $rows = $(input).parents('tr:first').nextAll('tr:visible');
            $(input).click(function() {
                    if($(this).is(':checked')){
                            $rows.hide();
                    } else {
                            $rows.show();
                    }
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Not sure why I struggled with this. Now that I see the solution it makes total sense.